# Errors assigning to array of structs

Tags: c++, embedded, esp32

I'm reasonably new to c++. I'm currently trying to create and internet radio alarm clock on the ESP32. I've managed to play a station but I was wanting to test out changing between two stations. I've tried creating an array of Station structs to hold relevant info for each Station but I keep getting the same errors when trying to assign to the different elements in the array. It could be that it is quite a simple error but I can't figure it out and I can't see anything too similar anywhere else.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "WiFi.h"
#include <Audio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <SPI.h> 
#define I2S_DOUT     25
#define I2S_BCLK      27
#define I2S_LRC        26  
Audio audio;

#define SSID ""
#define PASSWORD "" 



//function to change station    
void changeStat() {
  int statIndex = (statIndex+1)%2; 
};



void connectToWiFi(){
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wifi"); 
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print('.'); 
    delay(1000); 
  }

  Serial.print("\n Connected \n");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   

  //Initialising array of station structures
  struct Station{
    char name[15];  
    char URL[130]; 
  };  

  Station Stats[2]; 
  int statIndex = 0;

  Stats[0] = {"BBC 6Music", "http://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_6music"};
  Stats[1] = {"BBC Rad4", "http://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_radio_fourlw"};

  connectToWiFi(); 
  audio.setPinout(I2S_BCLK, I2S_LRC, I2S_DOUT); 
  audio.setVolume(5); 
  audio.connecttohost(Stats[statIndex].URL);
}

void loop() {  

  audio.loop();
}
```

Specifically, the error I get on the lines `Stats[0] and Stats[1]` is
`no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'setup()::Station' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')`
but I have seen lots of other people using this sort of assignment

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6dbfbc3de38c133)

Comment: Maybe if you had [specified you were compiling in C++98 mode...](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/004c42e1778517cd)

Comment: It depends on what standard you have configured your compiler (e.g. using command line options) to support.   You're trying to use C++11 or later, but the code is invalid with standards predating C++11.    For older compilers use `Stats[0] = Station("BBC 6Music", "http://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_6music")` instead  (similarly for `Stats[1]`).   Or, better, do it in the definition/initialisation of `Stats`, viz  `Station Stats[2] = {{"BBC 6Music", "http://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_6music"}, {"BBC Rad4", "http://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_radio_fourlw"}};`

Answer (score 1):

This syntax uses [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), a feature added to C++ with it's 2011 version.

```
struct Station
{
    char name[15];  
    char URL[130]; 
};  

Station station = { "BBC 6Music", "http://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_6music" };
```

If you can, do switch to a more up to date compiler, at least handling C++14.

If not, you can still resort to C-style:

```
Station station;
strcpy(station.name, "BBC 6Music");
//...
```

An other solution would be to provide a user-defined constructor to `Station`:

```
struct Station
{
    char name[15];  
    char URL[130]; 
    Station(char const* _name, char const* _url) { /* ... */ }
};

Station station("BBC 6Music", "http://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_6music");
```

Comment: why "at least C++14" ?

Comment: C++14 is a fix of C++11. I wont recommand to switch to C++11 if C++14 is a possibility. C++17 or 20 are a possibility, but not a necessity.

Comment: Okay I've not really touched on constructors but I can kind of see how that works. Would you still say it's an easier route to update my compiler? I think it's a bit more elegant to store all of the stations in an array rather than have them floating. The thing is I'm using platformio so I am unsure of how to update the compiler with that.

Comment: @FinSmy Having `Station`s in an array or in free vraiables is almost orthogonal to the way it is constructed. If you intend to seriously code something in C++, get your hands on a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/5470596) and teach yourself how classes work.

Comment: I definitely will. I'm very interested in the field. That's why I'm so interested in getting stuck in and doing a project like this. As one last follow on question... in your opinion, what would be the best way of storing all of the stations then?

Comment: When unsure, go for `std::vector`. Only divert from that principle when you can explain why to a stubborn colleague.

Comment: Lovely. I'll give that a go. Cheers for all the help and advice.